# Is it a good practice to validate authorization at micro service level again when we have already authorized at API Gateway level.?

Tags: authentication, authorization, microservices, keycloak, kong

We are trying to come up with a microservice Architecture where we need to identify whether its a good practice to implement authorization at micro service level when we have already done that gateway level.
We are using KONG as API Gateway which will interact with KeyCloak for Authorization.
After the Authorization is successful, is it really correct to apply a global filter at the resource level that will verify the JWT token passed inside the header. May be performance can take a hit but I am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is useful but in my experience i would go for JWT only if the users who are gonna use the API are known and are not too many. Otherwise i always go for a basic auth which allows me to have way more control of the users and controll their privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally microservices should be accessible through API Gateway only. If that is the case in your scenario, then there no need to do authentication validation again.

Comment: I agree but then if all the authorization happens at gateway  level then if authz is compromised then all microservice will be open to malicious attacks. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Authorization is compromised means token is stolen or credential is stolen.. In both cases, even if you authorization at all microservice level then even it is not going to help.

Comment: You can add authorization at 2 levels - Gateway and Client(if you have specific client).. There are chances that you have 100s of microservices and communication mechanism is sync as well as async. So, it is not an good as well as feasible option to validate at all microservice level.